# Trying to find a UK Fantasy single player RPG Magazine from around 1992/3

Tags: story-identification, rpg

I think it was a single player Fantasy RPG magazine that gave you a story for you to work through and the first issue included a map of the world. Later issues gave you cards of monsters and such that would eventually turn out to be a sort of top trumps game.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this may be [The Ancestral Trail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ancestral_Trail).

I didn't remember it having any RPG elements, but Wikipedia states:

> "Within the inside flap back cover of each issue, as well as aerial fragments of a graphic map, enabling the reader to create an illustrated layout of the Ancestral World. Information cards were printed in each issue which outline the real world legends that the series' antagonists were based upon. These cards were replaced by 'Techscan Cards', which told the reader about various scientific principles and theories. Role-playing games based on the content were generated from both free trump card sets bundled with each issue and later printed within the inside cover."

Comment: This is it! I always thought it had an RPG element to it, no wonder I couldn't find it. 
Thank you!

Comment: The first sentence of the quote makes no sense at all. It seems that the editor of the wiki page didn't bother to reread his work.

Comment: @FreeMan I've looked at that article's edit history. It looks like that sentence started out as *"Role-playing games based on the content were published within the inside back cover of each issue, as well as fragments of an atlas, enabling the reader to create a map of the Ancestral World."*. That did make sense, but a future edit by that very same editor garbled it.

Answer (score 5):

This could be [Warlock Magazine (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warlock_(magazine)) / [web archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20160303204439/https://www.fightingfantasy.com/index.php?%20option=com_content&view=article&id=86&Itemid=37) as a complement to the existing [Fighting Fantasy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fighting_Fantasy) books

[image: Warlock 1 cover]

> 1992/3

A little older as it was 1984-1986.

> A story each issue

Each issue contained a unique adventure (early issues were rehashes or partials of existing / about to be released books)

> A map

First issue included a map of "Allansia" where many of the previous Fighting Fantasy  books were set.

> Cards of monsters

Each (didn't check them all) issue contains an "Out of the Pit" section which was more of a *monster manual* than top-trumps.

Comment: Sadly it wasn't this however I will be checking it out as it sounds great. 
Thank you anyway.